# How to fetch information randomly from files in C++?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, information-retrieval, ofstream

I am creating a quiz game in C++. So, the main requirement is that questions should be fetched randomly from file each time program runs. So, How can I do this in C++?
Consider following two simple programs.

**Write.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::ofstream;
using std::string;
int main()
{
    ofstream fout("test.txt");
    if(!fout)
        cout<<"Error in opening file";
    string s[3];
    s[0]="C++ provides object oriented string handling";
    s[1]="C++ provides object oriented exception handling";
    s[2]="C++ provides highest flexibility to the programmer";
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        fout<<s[i]<<'\n';
    fout.close();
}
```

**Read.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    if(!fin)
        cout<<"Error in opening file";
    string s[3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        getline(fin,s[i]);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        cout<<s[i]<<'\n';
    fin.close();
}
```

What should I do so that when I compile Read.cpp & run Read.exe file the 3 strings should be fetched randomly from file & gets displayed?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add more details about your problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @Ilya: I have provide enough details about my problem. What else you need?

Comment: If each line of the file is a possible target string, and you know the total number of lines in your file, you could generate 3 random number from range `1 .. line_count`, then iterate through your file and store each line corresponding to each randomly generated number

Comment: @Ploutox: It would be better if you write an answer & explain it using the program.

Comment: @PravasiMeet, it is not obvious now, algoritmical or technical problem do you have. Do you need description of algorithm which can show strings of array in random order? Or do you need information how to get random values in c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want to maintain the array of strings in the order you read them from the file**

You can achieve that by creating another integer array that contains the numbers [1, 2 .. n-1] (where n is the number of strings) and then shuffling it to obtain a randomized sequences of indices, which you can use to print the strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    if(!fin)
        cout<<"Error in opening file";

    std::vector<string> lines;
    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line))
          lines.push_back(line);

    // Create a std::vector containing {1, 2 .. n-1} 
    // and shuffle it to obtain a random ordering.
    std::vector<int> order;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
    {
       order.push_back(i);
    }

    // C++11
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count(); // Seed from current time.
    auto engine = std::default_random_engine{seed}; // You may also want to look into uniform_int_distribution.
    std::shuffle(std::begin(order), std::end(order), engine);

    // C++98
    // std::random_shuffle(order.begin(), order.end());

    // Prints strings in random order.
    for (int number : order)
         cout << lines[number] <<'\n';

    fin.close();
}
```

**If you can modify (shuffle) the string array**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    if(!fin)
        cout<<"Error in opening file";

    std::vector<string> lines;
    string line;
    while (getline(fin, line))
          lines.push_back(line);

    // C++11
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count(); // Seed from current time.
    auto engine = std::default_random_engine{seed}; // You may also want to look into uniform_int_distribution.
    std::shuffle(std::begin(lines), std::end(lines), engine);

    // C++98
    // std::random_shuffle(lines.begin(), lines.end());

    // Prints strings in random order.
    for (string& line : lines)
         cout << line <<'\n';

    fin.close();
}
```

[Try it online!](http://cpp.sh/86np)

Comment: I tried your solutions, but the same output I am getting every time. Looks like strings aren't getting displayed randomly.

Comment: If you are using c++ 11 standard, consider using `shuffle` instead of `random_shuffle`.

Comment: Added C+11 version with `shuffle` which is considerably more random that `random_shuffle`

Comment: @Banex: Still I am getting same output when I run program multiple times.  Yes, first time when I test your suggested solution then it prints randomly but when I execute the program multiple times strings are printed in same sequence. What's happening wrong here?

Comment: @PravasiMeet I added the seed obtained from current time. Please try it out. I've also added a link to a snippet you can test online.

Comment: @Banex: Oh sorry. I didn't observe it. u already updated ur answer. It really works according to my expectations. Thanks for valuable help.

Comment: @Banex Can i safely say, without using time seed, shuffle generates same sequence of numbers every time?

Comment: @Nishant Without explicitly providing a seed, `default_random_engine` uses a default seed. So indeed it generates the same sequence of numbers (I overlooked it at first).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to put you lines into `std::list`, then use `std::random_shuffle` to reorder them randomly:

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::random_shuffle
#include <list>         // std::list
#include <ctime>        // std::time
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand, std::srand
std::list<std::string> str_list;
std::string buf_str;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  getline(fin,buf_str);
  str_list.push_back(buf_str);
}
std::srand(std::time(0));
std::random_shuffle ( str_list.begin(), str_list.end() );
// then just print lines from str_list
```